# How to fix "TypeError: rule.assign is not a function" when trying to import ReactToastify.css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, react-toastify

I can `import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify` with no problems, but when I try to
`import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';`, I get an error:

```
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css
```

TypeError: rule.assign is not a function

I'm using next.js and tailwind css with 'jit' mode enabled.

_app.js:

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import '../public/css/syles.css';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
// dynamic(
//   () =>
//     import('!style-loader!css-loader!react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'),
//   { ssr: false }             <== tried this as a potential fix, but didn't work.
// );
// import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer position='top-center' />
      <NavBar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "heroicons": "^1.0.5",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.3",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Have you tried deleting the `.next` folder and running the app again?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, I tried it, but still the same error, except now it also shows `TypeError: rule.assign is not a function
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved it by { injectStyle } and executing in useEffect().

I referred to this page: https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/how-to-style/#inject-style-on-demand

_app.js:

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import '../public/css/syles.css';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { injectStyle } from 'react-toastify/dist/inject-style';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    injectStyle();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer position='top-center' />
      <NavBar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```